# Given the coordinates of the vertices of a triangle, what is an efficient way of classifying said triangle?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, euclidean-geometry

Given the coordinates of all vertices of a triangle, what is an efficient way of determining which of the followig propreties the triangle has?

i) Right

ii) Isoceles

iii) Scalene

I am asking this question in order to be able to help college algebra students so I am interested in an approach using only basic tools, but I am also more advanced tools for my own personal interest.

I know that ii) and iii) can be determined by just calculating the length of each side using the distance formula. i) can be calculated by checking if the slopes of any of the sides are negative reciprocals of each other. But this is very time consuming; is there a better way?

Comment: By "efficient", do you mean that you could do in your head, or that a computer could do?  Because if you mean the latter, you could adjust the three points so one of them is at the origin, then rotate the other two so one is on the $x$-axis, then scale it so that one is at $(1,0)$.  From here, you should be able to tell everything from where the third point is.  Of course, doing this mentally is prohibitive.

Comment: @Mark Primarily I am looking for methods which you would want to do with paper and pencil (for professional interest) but I would be very interested in and appreciate any other methods as well.

Comment: which coordinates are given?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner The three coordinates of the vertices of the triangle; in the Euclidean plane, in Cartesian form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know that you can do much better than actually calculating the $3$ squared lengths of the sides (squared, as to save some square-root calls) then:

- if either are equal, then it's an isosceles triangle;
- if the largest is the sum of the other two then it's a right triangle;
- if neither of the above (which are *not* mutually exclusive), then it's a scalene triangle.

Comment: I think you have a typo in your second bullet point :P

Comment: @Ovi That refers to the *squared* lengths, as stated, so it's just Pythagoras' reciprocal.

Comment: Oh sorry I missed that haha

Comment: I think your classification can also include the determination of whether the triangle is acute/obtuse.

Comment: @Mick Right, and at virtually no additional computational expense. It would be an obtuse triangle iff the squared largest side is larger than the sum of the squares of the two others (by the law of cosines).